# Riemann Integral Example

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Can someone explain this Riemann Integral Example from Bartle's book, I dont quite understand what the author means by 'counting the tags twice' and I also dont understand his choice of delta.
[image: Can someone explain this Riemann Integral Example from Bartle's book, I dont quite understand what the author means by 'counting the tags twice' and I also dont understand his choice of delta.]

Is
$$ G(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1n\mathbb{1}_{\{\tfrac1n\}}(x)$$

Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: It means that if $I_k=[x_{k-1},x_k]$ and $I=_{k+1}=[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ are to adjacent subintervals in the partition, you may allow the tag $t_k\in I_k$ and the tag $t_{k+1}\in I_{k+1}$ to be the same, namely $t_k=t_{k+1}=x_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take the interval $[a,b]$ and putting a partition onto it.  The partition is sufficiently fine than no sub-interval has a width greater than $\delta_\epsilon.$  We look at the upper sum.  That is the maximum point in each sub interval, multiplied by the width of the sub-interval, and sum across all of sub intervals.

In the specific example $G(x) = \frac {1}{n}$ when $x=\frac {1}{n} \forall n\in \mathbb N$ and $0$ otherwise.  And we are evaluating over the interval [0,1]

We can ignore all of the points where $G(n) < \epsilon$ because, even if we multiply these by the entire length of the interval, the sum of these points will be less than $\epsilon.$

Now we need the sum over all partitions that include a point where $G(x) > \epsilon$

For any epsilon there is an $N$ such that $n>N \implies \frac {1}{n} < \epsilon$

Which implies that are $N$ points where $G(x) > \epsilon.$

It is possible for any of these points to be an endpoint of a sub-interval, which makes it also and endpoint of the neighboring sub-interval.  Even if we count every point twice, there are less than $2N$ sub-intervals where $G(x)>\epsilon$

$G(x) < 1$ over ever one of these sub intervals.

The upper sum over these sub-intervals is less than $(2N)\delta_\epsilon$

Now lets choose $\delta_\epsilon = \frac {\epsilon}{2} = \frac {1}{2N}$

We broke our interval in two, and the upper sum of each piece is less than $\epsilon$

And we can make $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small.